# Launching Appium Service programmatically failing

Tags: java, node.js, maven, appium

I have an Appium test project that was created about nine months ago, and was working fine.  I'd since that time attempted to work on that project again, and the project works, but only if I start Appium manually (with the desktop app).  The project checks for the server to see if it's already running, and if not, launches it using the service logic below:

```
public class AppiumServer {

    AppiumDriverLocalService service = null;

    public void InitAppiumServer() {

        System.out.println("Creating Appium Service . . .");
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
        System.out.println("Appium Service created.  URL: '" + service.getUrl().toString() + "'");

    }

    public void startServer() {

        System.out.println("Starting Appium Service . . .");
        service.start();
        System.out.println("Appium Service started.");

    }
```

The resulting output, when Appium is not started manually, is below:

> Creating Appium Service . . . Appium Service created.  URL:
>   'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub' Checking for Appium Service on port 4723
>   . . . No prior Appium Service detected. Starting Appium Service . . .
>   io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException:
>   The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js
>   executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Arguments:
>   [C:\Users\m1033792\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js,
>   --port, 4723, --address, 0.0.0.0]

If I open a command prompt and run that command line manually, it also works, just not using the standard method that I've been using and it would see, from research, most others are using.  I also seem to not be the only person with this particular problem as I'm seeing it posted many places on the web, but with no responses.

My nodejs is version 5.6.0
Appium (via nvm install) is 1.8
Java is 1.8.0_144
Maven is 3.5.4

Comment: Hi there, would you be able to post the code from AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService() ? We know Appium works from running the command manually so it might be something in the code.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but there's no code to post.  It's from an imported library: `io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService`

Comment: Hmm, which java client version for appium are we using? I see that they did a few patches a while back in version 3.3.0. Also, I found this from  the java client's docs

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/000964148ddf5cd55f28a13497ab92d6264a2489/docs/The-starting-of-an-app-using-Appium-node-server-started-programmatically.md#fyi

it sounds like what might be happening is the command in the java program is using a different node.js executable

Comment: I thought I had the most-recent stable version, but it was at 5.0.0.  I updated the pom.xml with 5.0.4 and tried again with the same results.  I might try the beta 6 version if all else fails.  I also came across the page to which you linked, but I'm not sure where another node.exe would be located.  Going to look into that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive research and trial-and-error, I looked deeper into the stack trace and noticed that it referred to:

> com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter

As "not existing"  Further research showed others with the same problem with other services, not necessarily the Appium Server, and it was tied to my guava being at version 21.0 instead of 23.0.

Once I updated that setting in my pom.xml, the project ran error-free once again.

This is on me for not posting the -entire- stack trace in my question.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

In case still you have the problem, please try the below snippet, it will perfectly work.

static AppiumDriverLocalService appium;

```
public static void start() throws IOException {
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
            .withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/appiumServerLog.txt"));
    appium = builder.build();
    System.out.println("Starting the Appium Server on 127.0.0.1:4723");
    appium.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with Appium must be installed via npm .
Please check that is there any exisiitinh node.exe to avoid potwntial start errors  by 
killing the node.exe to avoid errors because we start appium via node js like killing chrome driver exe

Here is the code to start the appium

```
@BeforeClass
    public void appiumServerStart() {

        //Build the Appium service
                builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
                builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1"); 
                //127.0.0.1 is the  localhost normally resolves to the IPv4  127.0.0.1
                builder.usingPort(4723); //Appium default port
                builder.withCapabilities(cap);
                builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
                builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"error");

                //Start the server with the builder
                service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
                service.start();
                System.out.println("Appium Server Started via Java");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work. This is with java-client version 8.3.0, we are capturing the appium logs also. The server will start and run on the given server and portNumber.

```
public void startAppiumServer(String server, int port){
 AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withIPAddress(server)
            .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.BASEPATH, "/wd/hub").usingPort(port).withLogFile(new File("logFile.txt"))
            .build();
    service.start();
}
```

Since this is new version, Capabilities needs to be set in below format, below is the example for Andriod capabilities

```
public void setAppiumDriver(String server, int portNumber, String udid, String deviceName){
String appiumServer = "http://" + server + ":" + portNumber + "/wd/hub";
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(appiumServer);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    UiAutomator2Options androidOptions = new UiAutomator2Options().setPlatformName("Android")
            .setDeviceName(deviceName).setUdid(udid).setApp("testApp.apk");
    appiumDriver = new AndroidDriver(url, androidOptions);
    return appiumDriver;
}
```